# Ошибка при попытке удаления строки в базе данных

Tags: android, база-данных, dialogfragment

При попытке удалить запись из базы данных приложение падает

Класс бд (с методом удаления - deleteTaskFromDB)

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDataBase";
public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static String DATABASE_TABLE = "MyTable";
public static String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static String KEY_TEXT = "text";

public DataBase( Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," + KEY_TITLE + " text," + KEY_TEXT + " text" + ");");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

void deleteTaskFromDatabase (SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "_id" + KEY_ID, null);

}
```

}

Список, из которого хочу удалить с помощью диалогового окна

```
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(dataBase.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, 
null, null);
    simpleCursorAdapter = new MySimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            DeleteTaskDialogFragment deleteDialog = new DeleteTaskDialogFragment();
            deleteDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "custom");
        }
    });
```

Диалоговое окно (в нем и падает при нажатии кнопки "Да")

```
public class DeleteTaskDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

DataBase dataBase = new DataBase(getContext());
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    return dialogBuilder.setTitle("Подтверждение удаления").setMessage("Вы действительно хотите удалить заметку?")
            .setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();
                    dataBase.deleteTaskFromDatabase(sqLiteDatabase);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Удалено!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Вы нажали кнопку - нет", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .create();



}
```

}

Ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.adapter, PID: 9894
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:352)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
    at com.example.adapter.DeleteTaskDialogFragment$2.onClick(DeleteTaskDialogFragment.java:26)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:172)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Мне кажется я неправильно вызвал метод deleteTaskFromDB. 
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Фрагменты, как и активити, создаются системой и получают доступ к контексту в процессе вызова системой методов их жизненного цикла. Это означает, что в процессе инициализации класса контекст в экземпляре не доступен. А вы как раз и пытаетесь его использовать. Чтобы убрать ошибку вам надо использовать контекст там, где он уже есть. Для этого перенестите строку

> DataBase dataBase = new DataBase(getContext());

в метод `onCreateDialog()`